# Create a matrix from variables in a data structure

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, data-structures

I have a data structure which contains 1520 values. Is it possible to create a matrix using a for loop instead of writing out the matrix manually? The data points are named U_Velocity1 to U_Velocity1520. I'm trying to make a 18x40 matrix where the first column is made from values of U_Velocity1 to 18 and the seconds column is made from the values of U_Velocity19 to 76 and so on. Regards Jer

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you try anything yet? Please paste your code and tell if you have any errors. You can use `struct2array` and `reshape`.

Comment: I was using this but I know this is wrong `for gg = 1:1520
U_Matrix(1:18,1:40) = [MeanU_Velocity.U_Velocity]
end`

Comment: The data structure has 1520 fields? i.e. if the structure was A, then A.U_Velocity1 = some number, A.U_Velocity2 = some number, ... , A.Uvelocity1520 = some number?

Comment: I recommend to use one struct field `U_Velocity` which is a 1x1520 vector instead. Such enumerated variable names are rarely a good idea!

Comment: Yes that is how the data structure is laid out

Comment: How do you create a one struct field?

Comment: The real question is WHY are the fields named in such a crazy way? If you ever create field names that are numbered, then you have done something conceptually wrong. You should be using an array or cell array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the following example:

```
s.a1 = 1;
s.a2 = 3;
s.a3 = 5;
s.a4 = 10;
arr = reshape(struct2array(s),2,2)

arr =

     1     5
     3    10
```

Just replace the numbers and variables with your code.